# Filter entire correlation matrix for a value

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, correlation

I want to filter a correlation matrix by a certain correlation coefficient.

I have a massive (over 500 columns) and several thousands of rows of data and I have a correlation matrix for a slightly smaller set. I want to filter the matrix to obtain variables that have a certain correlation. (For eg, those with correlation less than -0.50)

I tried using the below because I could use a similar code to filter a dataframe for all columns with zeroes. But with the below, I always get an empty list;

`corrM.columns[(corrM < -0.5).all()]`

I am not sure if the below makes any sense, but I tried to access the values attribute of a dataframe:

`corrM.columns[pd.DataFrame(corrM.values < -0.5).all()]`

I want a filtered correlation matrix and the set of columns that have these coefficients.

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset and example please?

Comment: i realize the data is a bit of a mess; I am in the process of cleaning further; I will post a sample soon.